# task that uses forEach is not completing

Tags: javascript, gulp

Rather new to both gulp and javascript. The script I wrote is returning an error (appended at the end of the post.)

This is the minimal example file:

```
const {src, dest, series, parallel }= require('gulp');
const sourceList = ['about', 'contact', 'projects'];

// Next 2 functions take each html file and move them to respective dist folder.

function eachHtml(){
  sourceList.forEach(function(htmlFile){
    cphtmlTask(`source/${htmlFile}/${htmlFile}.html`, `dist/${htmlFile}/`)
  });
  //cphtmlTask('source/index.html', 'dist/');
}

function cphtmlTask(i,o){
  return src(i)
    .pipe(dest(o));
}

exports.default = series(eachHtml);
```

**Output**

```
[17:55:19] Starting 'default'...
[17:55:19] Starting 'eachHtml'...
[17:55:19] The following tasks did not complete: default, eachHtml
[17:55:19] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is:

```
function eachHtml(cb){

  sourceList.forEach(function(htmlFile){
    cphtmlTask(`source/${htmlFile}/${htmlFile}.html`, `dist/${htmlFile}/`)
  });

  cb();

 //cphtmlTask('source/index.html', 'dist/');
}
```

That `cb` is a callback function which will signal to gulp that the `eachHtml` task has completed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found it also in [gulp website](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#using-an-error-first-callback). Should read the docs.

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Your task is a little trickier because it uses `forEach` so the usual way of signaling async completion (by adding a `return` statement)  doesn't work.